# Minimal Android app with Google Play Services SDK (Passes API) not work

Tags: java, android, google-play-services, android-native-library

I have bare Android application created in Android Studio to which I added this Google Services API dependency: `implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-pay:16.0.0'`

Now I am trying to access `Passes API` in Main activity like so:

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        GoogleApiAvailability g = new GoogleApiAvailability();

        Log.e("Is available?", g.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this) + "");

        PayClient payClient = Pay.getClient(this);
    }
}
```

Availability check (line 10) returns `0` which means SUCCESS, but when I try to get `PayClient` by `Pay.getClient(this)` I get this error:

```
2021-08-01 22:09:05.183 4722-4748/com.example.app E/GoogleApiManager: Failed to get service from broker. 
    java.lang.SecurityException: GoogleCertificatesRslt: Package signed with unknown certificate (go/gsrlt)
        at android.os.Parcel.createExceptionOrNull(Parcel.java:2373)
        at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:2357)
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2340)
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2282)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.IGmsServiceBroker$Stub$zza.getService(com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement@@17.5.0:14)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.BaseGmsClient.getRemoteService(com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement@@17.5.0:281)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zabj.run(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@17.5.0:11)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)
```

I have my app signed by valid certificate and I have same SHA fingerprints added by Google Support (as described [here](https://developers.google.com/pay/passes/guides/basic-setup/get-access-to-android-sdk)) and I am following this tutorial to add Loyalty card trough native api: https://developers.google.com/pay/passes/guides/implement-the-api/save-passes-to-google-pay?feed=native-android-app#call-android-sdk

Any ideas what is wrong?